# how to match a URL inside a HTML comment with regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I'm making an automated script with PHP to check if my link exists at my partner website ( link exchange) .. besides making sure my link exists in the source code , I want to make sure he is not placing it in a HTML comment like `<!-- http://www.mywebsite.com -->` and cheating me ..

I tried to match it with REGEXP , but have failed

Answer (score 3):

Use the DOM and XPath, it ignores comments:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlstring);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $xpath->query('//a[contains(@href, "mywebsite.com")]');

if (!$result->length) echo "You've been cheated\n";
```

And then if you still want to know if your website is being commented out

```
if (strpos($htmlstring, 'mywebsite.com') !== false && !$result->length)
   echo "Your partner is hiding your link in a comment, sneaky bastard\n";
```

Comment: seems like it will only check the existence of the url . will this notify my link is inside a comment !?

Comment: Updated to account for commented links

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect use for an HTML parser like [`DOMDocument->loadHTML()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and look for an anchor tag with your link. He could still remove it via javascript on the browser side, but that's a different issue.

If it's a cat and mouse game of "are you showing a link to my site" using a standard parser is your best bet. There are just too many [ways for a regex to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) on html.